# How to sync objects which are modified/uploaded in certain time range from a AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 bucket in which many files are being uploaded daily by many users. I am writing a consumer application to list the objects based on given date range. 
**Note** : I cannot get all the objects and sort them because, there will be atleast 5k files uploaded daily.If I request all objects, my application doesn't scale as the number of files increases. I have to some how request the bucket for the files which are uploaded/modified in a certain range. How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS S3 API's `list-objects` can take a `--query` argument where you can filter based on the contents of the objects' `LastModified` metadata. The documentation for `list-objects` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) has an example that queries on key and value but it should be simple to modify to change to query on `LastModified` instead.

However, have you considered modifying your S3 directory structure to use a date prefix for the modified files? This would remove the need to filter as you could list the modified files by their prefix.

Comment: I'd bet money that this feature in aws-cli, if it works as described, will perform horribly... as far as I can tell, neither V1 nor V2 of the underlying List Objects API supports such a query, which means aws-cli is scanning the entire bucket and discarding objects not matching the "query." Yikes.